# Aggregate function not working when deleting last instance on model

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have an aggregate function that gives a top-level array result on my 'one' in a 'one to many' db relationship. It sums the individual years for all the related 'many' documents.

It works fine, except when all the instances belonging to that particular 'one' are deleted - although the instances are indeed deleted, my aggregate function still operates as if the last instance exists.

This is my function:

```
outputSchema.statics.calcSumYears = async function (projectId) {
const stats = await this.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { project: projectId }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$project',
            year1: { $sum: { $arrayElemAt: ['$afterActivity', 0] } },
            year2: { $sum: { $arrayElemAt: ['$afterActivity', 1] } },
            year3: { $sum: { $arrayElemAt: ['$afterActivity', 2] } }
        }
    }
])
let outputYearsTotal = [stats[0].year1, stats[0].year2, stats[0].year3]

if (stats.length > 0) {
    await Project.findByIdAndUpdate(projectId, {
        $set: {
            outputYearsTotal: outputYearsTotal
        }
    })
} else if (stats.length === 0) {
    await Project.findByIdAndUpdate(projectId, {
        $set: {
            outputYearsTotal: [0, 0, 0]
        }
    })
}
}
```

I can delete instances without a problem until I reach the last one, when I delete this the query returns 'cannot read property 'year1' of undefined', which makes sense as the aggregate function has no instances to operate on.

As shown in the code above, I tried to reset this by adding an array of zeroes if the 'stats' variable length is 0, however this doesn't work.

I think I have looked at this too long, fundamentally all I want to do is ensure that if the last instance of this model that matches the query (ie belongs to that projectId) is deleted, that the 'outputYearsTotal' array in my findByIdAndUpdate query is reset to 0.

Answer (score 1):

add $exists in the initial Match..so that it also is only looking at docs that where the field exists, meaning that it will be 0 when there are no docs - which is a legit value rather than throw an error